# How to select all data from table if user login correct flutter

Tags: flutter

I try to make page of user login to my app. page is work now but I need to do same thing also.I need to select all data of this user if user login correct.

I use this code to login:

```
     var url = 'http://xxxxxxxx/login_user.php';
      var data = {'email': email, 'password' : password};
      var response = await http.post(url, body: json.encode(data));
      var message = jsonDecode(response.body);
       print("tapped ${data}");
      if(message == 'Login Matched')

      {
        setState(() {
          visible = false;


        });

        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => mainpage(email : emailController.text)));
      }else{
        setState(() {
          visible = false;

        });
```

```
<?php
include 'connt.php';
 
 $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
 $obj = json_decode($json,true);
 $email = $obj['email'];
 $password = $obj['password'];
 $loginQuery = "select * from user_registration where email = '$email' and password = '$password' ";
 $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$loginQuery));
    if(isset($check)){
         $onLoginSuccess = 'Login Matched';
         $SuccessMSG = json_encode($onLoginSuccess);
         echo $SuccessMSG ; 
     }
    
     else{
    
        $InvalidMSG = 'Invalid Username or Password Please Try Again' ;
        $InvalidMSGJSon = json_encode($InvalidMSG);
         echo $InvalidMSGJSon ;
     
     }
 
 mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I have in my table different fields as lastname , age , tell..'

I need to select all fields.Now if I try to see data by this code:

```
 print("tapped ${data}");
```

just I have email and password.So if anyone have idea how can i do that please help me.

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:onefrist/main.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'MyPreferences.dart';
import 'main.dart';
import 'Registration.dart';


void main() => runApp(loginpage());

var id;
class loginpage extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
                title: Text('User Login Form')),
            body: Center(
                child: LoginUser()
            )
        )
    );
  }
}

class LoginUser extends StatefulWidget {
  LoginUserState createState() => LoginUserState();

}

class LoginUserState extends State <LoginUser>{
  MyPreferences _myPreferences = MyPreferences();


  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    _myPreferences.init().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        _myPreferences = value;
        check_if_already_login();
      });
    });
  }



  void check_if_already_login() async {
   if (_myPreferences.password !=null && _myPreferences.user !=null) {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>mainpage ()));
   }else{

   }
  }

  bool visible = false ;
  Future userLogin() async{
    setState(() {
      visible = true ;

    });

    final emailController = TextEditingController(text: _myPreferences.user);
    final passwordController = TextEditingController(text: _myPreferences.password);
   // final idController = TextEditingController();
    // Getting value from Controller
    String email = emailController.text;
    String password = passwordController.text;
   // String id = idController.text;
    if(email == '' || password == '')
    {
      // Put your code here which you want to execute when Text Field is Empty.
      print('Text Field is empty, Please Fill All Data');
    }else{

      var url = 'http://192.168.8.105/login_user.php';
      var data = {'email': email, 'password' : password};
      var response = await http.post(url, body: json.encode(data));
      var message = jsonDecode(response.body);
       print("tapped ${data}");
      if(message == 'Login Matched')

      {
        setState(() {
          visible = false;


        });

        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => mainpage(email : emailController.text)));
      }else{
        setState(() {
          visible = false;

        });

        // Showing Alert Dialog with Response JSON Message.
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: new Text(message),
              actions: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  child: new Text("OK"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        );}
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final emailController = TextEditingController(text: _myPreferences.user);
    final passwordController = TextEditingController(text: _myPreferences.password);
    final idController = TextEditingController();
    return Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[

                  Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                      child: Text('User Login Form',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 21))),

                  Divider(),

                  Container(
                      width: 280,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: emailController,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          _myPreferences.user = value;
                          _myPreferences.commit();
                        },
                        autocorrect: true,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter Your Email Here'),
                      )
                  ),

                  Container(
                      width: 280,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: passwordController,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          _myPreferences.password = value;
                          _myPreferences.commit();
                        },
                        autocorrect: true,
                        obscureText: true,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter Your Password Here'),
                      )
                  ),
                  Container(
                      width: 280,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: idController,
                        autocorrect: true,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter Your Password Here'),
                      )
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: userLogin,
                    color: Colors.green,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(9, 9, 9, 9),
                    child: Text('Click Here To Login'),

                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    disabledColor: Colors.grey,
                    disabledTextColor: Colors.black,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    splashColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => RegisterUser()
                      ),);
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      "Reistraion page",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Visibility(
                      visible: visible,
                      child: Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30),
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator()
                      )
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )));
  }

}
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1839439) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text or using MD5/SHA1!** Only store password hashes created using PHP's [`password_hash()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), which you can then verify using [`password_verify()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). Take a look at this post: [How to use password_hash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30279321/1839439) and learn more about [bcrypt & password hashing in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337021/1839439)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can have only email and password if you print `data`. 
Consider `print(message)`. 
 This can show the data which is received from the server!
Also in your server, consider sending all data as a response.

```
$check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$loginQuery));
if($check){
     $check['password'] = '';
    // Make sure you are not returning the password for security reasons!
     $check['result'] = 'Login Matched';
     $SuccessMSG = json_encode($check);
     echo $SuccessMSG ; 
 }

 else{
    $InvalidMSG= array("result"=>"Invalid Username or Password Please Try Again");
    $InvalidMSGJSon = json_encode($InvalidMSG);
     echo $InvalidMSGJSon ;
 
 }
```

In your dart code, you could simply do this.

```
if(message['result'] == 'Login Matched')
{
  // Do Something
}else{
  // Do Something
}
```

Comment: Hi brother .Thank you, it works, yes now, but I have how can I take only one field? Because now I see all fields for the user and I only need to take the id

Comment: I make print(message) now and I see all data of user I just need to take id

Comment: Try using `message['your column name']`. in your case, `message['id']`.